# Unable to set Comobject Value

Tags: powershell, ms-word, com

I have a snippet of code that opens a word template, then attempts to set values of named FormFields.

```
$options = @{
    'foo' ='bar';
    'bizz' = 'buzz';
}

$document = 'C:\Form_template.doc'
$word = new-object -ComObject Word.application
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($document)
$word.visible = $true
$fields = $doc.FormFields
$fields.item('foo').Result = $options['foo']
$fields.item('bizz').Result = $options['bizz']
```

When running this snippet, the form fields are not set properly. However, when I run

```
$fields.item('foo').Result = 'bar'
$fields.item('bizz').Result = 'buzz'
```

The values are set as desired.

**Edit**: Here's an example in Interactive shell

```
PS C:\>$fields.item('foo').Result = $options['foo']
PS C:\>$fields.item('bizz').Result = $options['bizz']
PS C:\> $doc.FormFields.Item('foo').Result

PS C:\> $doc.FormFields.Item('bizz').Result

PS C:\>#Now let's try setting the values directly with a string.
PS C:\>$fields.item('foo').Result = 'bar'
PS C:\>$fields.item('bizz').Result = 'buzz'
PS C:\> $doc.FormFields.Item('foo').Result
bar
PS C:\> $doc.FormFields.Item('bizz').Result
buzz
```

Why am I not able to set the FormField values using values from the hash?

Comment: `$options['foo']` is `'bar'`, so the same command statically using the value would be `$fields.item('foo').Result = 'bar'`

Comment: BenH - Thus my question. They should be the same thing, but they produce different results.

Comment: Your example line that worked was: `$fields.item('foo').Result = 'foo'` not `$fields.item('foo').Result = 'bar'`

Comment: whats the difference? @BenH he's talking about the fact that the value doesn't get assigned in one case and does in another...

Comment: Try `$fields.item('bizz').Result = [string]$options['bizz']` ???

Answer (score 0):

Per a suggestion from [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587803/ben) casting the string with `[string]$options['bizz']` resulted in setting the value correctly.

```
PS C:\>$fields.item('bizz').Result = [string]$options['bizz']
PS C:\> $doc.FormFields.Item('foo').Result
buzz
```

Upon further investigation I found that casting the hash value to string returned a different type vs using `.toString()`

```
PS C:\> $options['bizz'].getType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                    

PS C:\> $options['bizz'].toString().getType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                    

PS C:\> [string]$options['bizz'].getType()
string
```

I'm interested in why that is, but that would be a topic for another thread. Proper casting resolved my issue.

Comment: this is weird, since I've done the same and `Get-Member` showed that both are strings.

Comment: I started [this]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598901/inconsistent-comobject-property-behavior] thread on it, I'm curious to find out why we see this behavior, but I think it's better suited for it's own thread.